# Checking a parent table in a where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a `ProductDetail` table and a `Product` table.

Each `ProductDetail` has a "has_one" to Product called `ProductID`

The `Product` table has a column called `ShowOnTheseDomainTLDs` which I need to check when querying for specific `ProductDetails`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductDataValue FROM ProductDetail WHERE ProductDataName = 'Conjugate' AND Product.ShowOnTheseDomainTLDs IN ('AU', 'All') ORDER BY ProductDataValue ASC
```

I know `Product.ShowOnTheseDomainTLDs` is 100% incorrect but I have no idea what to do here to check the parent when there isn't actually a relationship on the table itself, the relationship is made in the php framework I am using

Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductDataValue FROM ProductDetail WHERE ProductDataName = 'Conjugate' AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) Product WHERE `ID` = ProductDetail.ProductID AND ShowOnTheseDomainTLDs IN ('AU', 'All')) > 0) ORDER BY ProductDataValue ASC
```

The main reason I don't want to use the ORM provided by the framework and use a direct SQL query instead is for performance reasons. I could loop through all records and check their parents ShowOnTheseDomainTLDs but that would add unnecessary overheads

Any help or pointers would be amazing

Comment: If I understand it correctly, then you can just use `JOIN` on the two tables as long as you have `ProductID` in both of your tables and then get the desired result (of course use the other predicates)

Comment: Product has `ID`, ProductDetail references it with `ProductID`, are you able to provide an example if possible ?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ProductDataValue
FROM ProductDetail a
JOIN Product b
ON (a.ProductID = b.ID)
WHERE a.ProductDataName = 'Conjugate'
AND b.ShowOnTheseDomainTLDs IN ('AU', 'All')
ORDER BY a.ProductDataValue ASC;`